# Is there any device/adapter that allows connecting DVI or HDMI display over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, lcd

I'm looking for a device that allows connecting LCD monitor remotely. Is there any device like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are products available to extend HDMI. Google for "HDMI wireless extender", there are many products available, specific product recommendations are off-topic here. However, as far as I know, all these devices are using custom wireless links, not Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

If your resolution is HD (1280p) or lower, and range is about 10 meters or less, solutions are available, although they are not cheap. However, if you need higher resolution or longer range, I'm afraid you won't find anything that works reliably. In that case, you can look into HDMI-over-UTP, which allows to run HDMI signals over regular ethernet cables, which are cheaper and easier to manager than HDMI cables.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any device/adapter that allows connecting DVI or HDMI display over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth?

[Yes it is called WiDi](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-wireless-display.html).